# Laravel 5.3 - Authentication is broken

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

About a year ago we took over an existing Laravel 5.1 site and upgraded to 5.3 - We recently became aware that an admin panel that was part of the old site no longer works (or unable to authenticate).

The original routes file contains the following:

```
//Login
 Route::controllers([
     'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
     'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
 ]);
//Admin
//Dashboard
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'), function() {

    //Dashboard
    Route::get('/webadmin', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index'));

});
```

Which after the upgrade stopped working as I understand the Route::controllers method was depreciated. We changed it to the following as I understand that was the replacement:

```
//Login
Route::resource('password','Auth\PasswordController');
Route::resource('auth','Auth\LoginController');
//Admin
//Dashboard
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'), function() {

    //Dashboard
    Route::get('/webadmin', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index'));
});
```

However, when we access the sites admin panel by example.com/admin/webadmin we are automatically redirect to example.com/login which then displays the dreadful NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php

This leads me to believe that the authentication middleware is not registered correctly. I am not sure what the correctly route is to take so will gladly appreciate any assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is happening because your not being authenticated and you are redirected to `login` route because the `unauthenticated` method in the `app\Exceptions\Handler` class redirects the user to `/login` using something like this:

```
return redirect()->guest('login');
```

So, you've to either create a `/login` route or change the above line to this:

```
return redirect()->guest('auth');
```

This should work and your `AuthController::index` method should show the login form because this will hit the `index` method in your `AuthController` because it's a resource controller.